# Best release strategy for POMs

Tags: git, maven, pom.xml, release

I am working in a project which has lot of standalone maven models, all of which together comprise the application. 
When they make a change to any of the module and get it ready to be released to Production, they update all OTHER poms to a new artifact version of the pom.
This I believe is to have a milestone for the application as a whole, i.e. in case there is a requirement to run a Past version of the project, they can simply choose all the modules of a particular version number from the repository.

I was thinking whether there could be another strategy mainly based on the fact we are updating pom's of modules which haven't changed at all.

Please advice the pros and cons of an alternative 'better' strategy if it exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be specific about options, because we don't know a lot about your project.  It seems like one way or another, dependency version specifications are a key concept here.

In a simple case, if I have Module A which uses Module B, and I modify Module B, I likely have to modify Module A to update its dependency information.  Because dependencies can be specified using version ranges, this isn't necessarily true; especially if you're using something like a true REST architecture to insulate one modules from changes in another.

But whether or not that's the case, it sounds like you're saying that *at least sometimes* your team updates the version number on a module *without even changing any of its dependency information*.  In an extreme example, maybe each module just provides a service with a strictly standardized interface; or maybe some other application uses the modules, but they don't use one another; or...

In that case, I guess the question is whether the cost of changing a version number (the literal cost of making the change, plus any semantic value the version numbers might otherwise convey) outweighs the simplicity your team might find from having synchronized version numbers.

Personally I would let the version numbers range independently, and use a "top-level" POM that knows what versions of each module work together to form "version X of the app as a whole".  This top-level POM should use specific version numbers, rather than ranges, in order to ensure reproducible build results.  Then, you modify whatever module(s) you modify, and you modify any module whose direct dependency information is affected (because it probably needs rebuilt anyway), and you modify the top-level POM, and that's all.

But that's just my take, and it only covers some common scenarios.  This is really something a team has to determine based on knowledge of the specific project.